# Calculating the sum of the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to calculate the sum of the following infinite series:
$$
S= 1\left(1^2 -\frac{1}{2^2 }\right)+ 2 \left(\frac{1}{2^2 }-\frac{1}{3^2}\right) +3\left(\frac{1}{3^2 }-\frac{1}{4^2}\right) +\cdots
$$

Comment: Pardon me, but doesn't this simplify to the well known $$1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots ~?$$

Comment: Well, of course :(. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
S & \equiv \color{#44f}{1\pars{1^{2} - {1 \over 2^{2}}} +
2\pars{{1 \over 2^{2}} - {1 \over 3^{2}}} +
3\pars{{1 \over 3^{2}} - {1 \over 4^{2}}} + \cdots}
\\[5mm] & = \lim_{n \to \infty}\ \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
k\bracks{{1 \over k^{2}} - {1 \over \pars{k + 1}^{2}}} \\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{1 \over k} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k + 1} +
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{k + 1}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{1 \over k} - \sum_{k = 2}^{n + 1}{1 \over k}} +
\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}
{1 \over k} - \pars{-1 +
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k} + {1 \over n + 1}}} +
\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}
\\[5mm] & = 1 +
\pars{-1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{2}}} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\pi^{2} \over 6}} \approx 1.6449
\end{align}